# How to find the time of an audio clip within longer clip Python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, audio-fingerprinting

I don't know what this would be called.

I am trying to find the timing a clip within a longer clip using python.

There is a jingle that is played, it is the same file played every time. I want to be able to find the exact position of this jingle in a longer audio clip so I can automatically trim an audio file to right after that jingle.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: What library are you using to process the audio clip?

Comment: one approach is called "Audio fingerprinting"  available in this lib https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu   also checkout https://github.com/adblockradio/stream-audio-fingerprint

Comment: Also see [chromaprint](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#chromaprint-1).